# On iOS , How to override the function loadrequest in UIWebview with Swift language

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview, swift

On iOS, How do I override the function `loadrequest` in `UIWebview` with `Swift` language?

I want to use the `UIWebview` to load my own page, and I have defined my protocol such as `polly://xxx?a=xx` in the page.

I want to process the URL which start with `polly://xxx` until the `UIWebview` load the URL. In iOS, we all know I should process in function should start load with request if I use the Object-C.

But I don't know how to override the function `loadrequest` in `UIWebview` with `Swift` language. Can someone tell me how to do (please provide code)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, There is no Programe-Master both foreign and domestic......